# Do moderators see which user has raised a flag?

Tags: support, faq, moderators, flagging

When a user flags a post for moderator attention, do the moderators see the name of the user who raised the flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators see who flagged a post for moderation attention. What they don't see is the users who flagged a comment.

#### Reference

- [Is my flagging data/history anonymous to volunteer/elected moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/is-my-flagging-data-history-anonymous-to-volunteer-elected-moderators)